# Filter Content using Jquery and Check Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter some content using Jquery and I have the Following Code:

HMTL:

```
    <div class="tags">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="flower" /> Flower </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="plants" /> Plants</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="beach" /> Beach </label>
    </div>

    <div class="photo plants flower " style="width:px; height:px;">
    Image 1            
    </div>
    <div class="photo flower beach " style="width:px; height:px;">
    Image 2            
    </div>
```

J Query:

```
    $(function(){
    $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
        var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
        //For each one checked
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
                $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
    });
   });
```

I can't get this code to work as im trying to filter based on the div class e.g `<div class="photo plants flower >`

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cR4gR/)

Comment: change is only for input elements and where is .results in your html...???

Comment: Image 1 and 2 are the results

Comment: but there's no such class in your html...

Comment: my html is `<div class="photo plants flower " style="width:px; height:px;">
    Image 1            
    </div>` and i want to filter and refine based on the div class

Comment: $('input:checked').each(function() {
   if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
      //do your stuff here
   }                
});

Comment: Where are the "<li>" and the element having class "result" in your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add jQuery library. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cR4gR/1/), and you trying to access elements which do not exist  `$('.results > li')`. there is no `li` and element with `result` class

```
  $(function(){
        $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
            var $lis = $('.photo').hide();
            //For each one checked 
            $('input:checked').each(function() {
                    $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        });
    });
```